# native client tutorial can't find libstdc++

Tags: google-nativeclient

I'm new to native client. I'm trying to follow the official tutorial on my newly installed ubuntu 14.

I'm getting the following when running "make serve" under the getting_started folder. I googled, it seems to be related to 32/64 bit. my system is 64bit, but pnacl seems to think it is 32.

Anyway I couldn't find a solution. do you know how?

/media/shi/work/nacl_sdk/pepper_34/toolchain/linux_pnacl/bin/pnacl-clang++ -o hello_tutorial.bc hello_tutorial.cc -O2 -I/media/shi/work/nacl_sdk/pepper_34/include -L/media/shi/work/nacl_sdk/pepper_34/lib/pnacl/Release -lppapi_cpp -lppapi
/media/shi/work/nacl_sdk/pepper_34/toolchain/linux_pnacl/host_x86_32/bin/clang: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [hello_tutorial.bc] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory `/media/shi/work/nacl_sdk/pepper_34/getting_started/part1'
make: *** [part1_ALL_TARGET] Error 2

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easiest to install the i386 C/C++ libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libstdc++6:i386
```

There are 64-bit binaries included in the SDK as well (in toolchain/linux_pnacl/bin64/), but they are not run by default (and I'm not certain of an easy way to make the SDK use them).